# Changing the second result of a function call with mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-mock

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    response = requests.post(some_url, some_params)
    if response.status_code != HTTPOk:
       # do something
```

What I would like to do is change response of requests.post in the second iteration of the loop. From within my test, I know I can do something like:

```
mock_response = mock.Mock()
mock_response.status_code = 404
with mock.patch(mymodule.requests.post, return_value=mock_response):
   mymodule.some_function()
```

But that only seems to work for one status_code. I looked at [side_effect](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect), and it looks like I can iterate through the loop like so:

```
mock_response.side_effect = [
    mock.Mock(status_code=400), mock.Mock(status_code=200)
]
with mock.patch(mymodule.requests.post, return_value=mock_response):
   mymodule.some_function()
```

However, it looks like it doesn't actually get the "right" status code. What's the best way of changing the behavior in side_effect or return_value to properly get the behavior I want? I think side_effect is what I want, but I'm not sure what the best way is to mock the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpler and cleaner way to do it is

```
with mock.patch("mymodule.requests.post", 
                side_effect=[Mock(status_code=400), Mock(status_code=200)]) as mock_post:
   mymodule.some_function()
```

[`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) create `mock_post` object by `MagicMock(side_effect=mock_responses)` and replace `mymodule.requests.post` reference. You can also use `mock_post` to check `post()` calls by something like:

```
mock_post.assert_has_calls([mock.call(first_url, first_params), mock.call(second_url, second_params)])
```

You can do the same work by build and configure `mock_post` before and then pass it as `new` parameter (the second `patch` argument) but by this way you have 2 downside

1. More code to write
2. Lose the ability to use `autospec=True` options in `patch`

[Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) is a very powerful feature of `mock` framework that prevent a lot of silly bug both in test and code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually turns out it was as simple as:

```
mock_response.side_effect = [
    mock.Mock(status_code=400), mock.Mock(status_code=200)
]
with mock.patch(mymodule.requests.post, mock_response):
   mymodule.some_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you wanted to have a different json body each time:

```
with mock.patch("mymodule.requests.post",
                    side_effect=[
                        Mock(status_code=400,
                        json=Mock(return_value=json_goes_here)),
                        Mock(status_code=200,
                        json=Mock(return_value=different_json_goes_here))]) as mock_post:
        mymodule.some_function()
```

Or you could use the @patch decorator:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

@patch('mymodule.requests.post', side_effect=[
    Mock(status_code=400, json=None),
    Mock(status_code=200, json=Mock(return_value=[
        {'coordinates': 'test1', 'reference': ''},
        {'coordinates': 'test2', 'reference': ''}])),
    Mock(status_code=200, json=Mock(return_value=[
        {'coordinates': 'test3', 'reference': ''},
        {'coordinates': 'test4', 'reference': ''}]))])
def test_query_packages_on_oss_index_api__happy_path_with_rate_limit_met(mock_response):
    mymodule.some_function()
```